# Understanding how Windows does Pattern Matching in Command Prompt

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have 500 files in a directory, test1.txt to test500.txt

From Microsoft's link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff469270.aspx, I did not clearly understand the difference between * and <

The following command in cmd-prompt throws "File  Not Found"

```
dir "test5<"
```

However `dir "test5<<"` lists all test5* files.

What is the reason for this behavior. I couldn't find any article that better explains how "<" is expected to behave.

[edit 1]

Also if there are no extensions i.e. files test1 - test500, `"test5???"` matches "test5", "test50" and "test500".

Isn't this supposed to give "file not found" as there are three ?'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<` is similar to `*`, except for one difference. `<` doesn't match the last `.` in the file name.

`test5<` doesn't match anything, because it doesn't match the file extension of the files in the directory.

`test5<<` matches them, because the first `<` matches the file names up until the `.` for the file extension and the second `<` matches the file extension itself.

Comment: that explains. thanks a lot. Also if there are no extensions, "test5???" matches "test5", "test50" and "test500". Isn't is supposed to give "file not found" as there are three ?'s

Comment: @SyncMaster The thing is, the site you posted explains the algorithm that only detects *if* a given file is a pattern. It doesn't fully explain how the pattern is *interpreted*. `?` probably means "zero or one" characters on the Windows Command Prompt. The explanations on that site could be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

The article you posted is discussing *algorithms*, not commands.

The `<` and `>` are [redirection operators](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) for the command prompt.

Comment: I am not using them as a redirection operator. I am using it inside a pattern to match files.

Comment: @SyncMaster Im not sure how to say this any clearer, it doesnt work that way

Comment: Actually, it does, Keltari.  Try it.  Prepare for yet another Microsoft `cmd` surprise.

Comment: Well thats new to me